# ¿Por qué inflamable y no flamable?

Tags: etimología, historia, terminología, comparación-de-idiomas, prefijos

En México, la gente a veces usa el adjetivo `flamable` en lugar del "correcto" `inflamable` para referirse a algo que puede encenderse con facilidad. Eso me dejó pensando, ¿por qué, en español, decimos `inflamable`?

Sobre todo considerando que el prefijo `in-` tiene las siguientes definiciones en el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=L9vLorj%7CL9vXSzQ):

> **in-<sup>1</sup>. 1. pref.** Suele significar 'adentro' o 'al interior'. Infiltrar, inseminación, implantar, irrumpir.
>
> **in-<sup>2</sup>. 1. pref.** Indica negación o privación. Inacabable, incomunicar, inacción, impaciencia, ilegal, irreal.

Comment: Podría ser por la influencia del inglés, *flammable*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En la propia pregunta aparece la respuesta. La primera acepción del prefijo "in-" es la clave.

En efecto, en este caso "in-" no es un prefijo de negación, sino que hace referencia a la preposición "en", y proviene del latín. El significado sería, como apunta guifa,

```
en-llamas-able.
```

Es decir, capaz de ponerse en llamas, y por tanto que puede arder. Por el contrario, "flamable" sería algo como "capaz de convertirse en una llama", que no es lo mismo.

*PD: Enviar al Dr. Nick Riviera de los Simpsons, en clara alusión, jaja https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efDYvtj2Rlo*

Fuente: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?inflamable

Comment: +1 por la referencia al Dr Nick. Es curioso que esta pregunta estuve a punto de hacerla, porque un día vi un camión cisterna que llevaba tanto la advertencia de "flamabe gas" como de "non-flamable" y me quedé pensando "Bueno, cuál de los dos llevas?" y me acordé del Dr. Nick también. Para rematar, complemento la respuesta con: "If something is *flammable* it means it can be set fire to, such as a piece of wood. However, *inflammable* means that a substance is capabble of bursting into flames without the need for any ignition" https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,,-78567,00.html

Comment: Además en la propia pregunta hay otro ejemplo muy claro: "inseminación"

Answer (score 4):

Viene del verbo *inflamar*, del latín *inflammare* que significaba poner en llamas.  *Flammare* existía en latín también, pero significaba generalmente *arder*, o estar en llamas.  Inflamar es el acto de hacer que otra cosa arda, y el sufijo **V.**<sup>-able</sup>/<sub>-ible</sub> significa *capaz de ser **V.**<sup>-ado</sup>/<sub>-ido</sub>*.  Así, algo *inflamable* es algo capaz de ser puesto en llamas (u hoy diríamos capaz de ser encendido).